# Distribution of integral with respect to Brownian motion in terms of the Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $M_t=\int_0^tX_udB_u$, where $X$ is progressive process. Then is it true that $M_1$ and $B_{\int_0^1X^2_udu}$ have same distribution?

It is true  when $X$ is deterministic, but can this be true when $X$ is random?

If true I am assuming one would employ Dubins-Schwarz Theorem to show, but I am not sure how to do it.

In particular,   Dubins-Schwartz says there exists  some BM $W$ such that  $M_t=W_{\int_0^t X_udu}$, but the joint distribution $(M,B)$ can be different from $(M,W)$?

Comment: Isn't it part of the statement of Dubins-Schwartz? As in https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/dubins-schwarz-theorem/

Comment: @Kore-N, thanks for your comment. I have edited question accordingly.   I am confused that Dubins-Schwartz says there exists some BM WW such that Mt=W∫t0XuduMt=W∫0tXudu, but the joint distribution (M,B)(M,B) can be different from (M,W)(M,W)?

Answer (score 0):

$M_{1}$ is centered Gaussian with variance $\int_{0}^{1}X_{u}^{2}du$. The same holds for $B_{\int_{0}^{1}X_{u}^{2}du}$.

Comment: Unless $X$ is deterministic the variance you have written is a random variable.